# Keep formatting in PHP DOMNode's InnerHTML

Tags: php, whitespace, domdocument

I have a HTML page, and want to extract some attributes from `HEAD` and the content from `BODY`. Extracting the attributes from `HEAD` works fine - but the content from `BODY` is **wrongly formatted**.

This is the HTML from file:

```
<ul>
  <li>test1</li>
  <li>test2</li>
</ul>
```

This is what `C14N()` (and also `DOMDocument::saveXML()`) makes of it:

```
<ul><li>test1</li>
  <li>test2</li>
</ul>
```

I ve also tried `DOMDocument::saveHTML()`:

```
<ul>
<li>test1</li>
    <li>test2</li>
</ul>
```

Imho the HTML loading goes wrong. That's how I currently construct the DOM:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$doc->formatOutput       = true;
$html = file_get_contents($path);
if ($doc->loadHTML($html)) {
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
  $bodyNode = $xpath->query("/html/body");
  $this->content = $doc->saveXML($bodyNode->item(0));
}
```

In `$html` the formatting is correct. `preserveWhiteSpace` and `formatOutput` have no impact.

Having the correct whitespace is not crucial - but it makes the code much better readable.

How to get the innerHTML from the `DOMNode` (returned by `DOMXPath::query()`) with correct whitespace?

Thanks.

Using PHP Version 7.0.29, DOM/XML API Version 20031129 and libxml Version 2.9.1.

Comment: you html  seems not well formed   (missing closing `</ul>` )

Comment: this is only a snipped... see source of http://km.kkrach.de/p_linux_video/ I will correct it in my question to avoid misunderstandings.